# Scrollable image to show in single screen android

Tags: android, scroll

I have a problem ... I have made a wallpaper app. But when i click on the image it shows me a scrollable image. I want to show the whole image in single screen.  The image shown in grid view. When a user click on the image it goes to the next screen and the full image is shown as scrollable. But i want to display the whole image in single screen that is i dont want to make that image scrollable. This is my code ..

```
> Blockquote

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@color/black">

     >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbLoader"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
    </ProgressBar>

    <!-- Scroll view for fullscreen preview -->

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgFullscreen"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <!-- Set as wallpaper button -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSetWallpaper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_corner"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ico_apply" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/set_wallpaper"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Download wallpaper button -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llDownloadWallpaper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_corner"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ico_download" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/download_wallpaper"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: changing the scaleType should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove image from  HorizontalScrollView let only imageview

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgFullscreen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```